# Why does `+=` not work with implicitly unwrapped optionals

Tags: swift, option-type, forced-unwrapping

Why does `+=` not work with implicitly unwrapped optionals, for instance:

```
var count: Int! = 10
count = count + 10 // This works
count += 10 // this does not work
```

Why isn't the optional implicitly unwrapped, like the case of `count = count + 10` ?

Comment: The operator needs a reference.

Comment: can you explain it more?

Comment: the function "+=" expends an Int. You are giving it an Int!.

Comment: You may append `?` to the left hand side of the `+=` operator , `count? += 10`, which likewise works if `count` is a "regular" optional, `Int?`. If its value is `nil`, the `+=` operator will do nothing, whereas if it is non-`nil`, it will do the work upon `.some(value)` to increase `value` by the right hand side.

Comment: if this is the case so why here count = count + 10 (Int! + 10 ) is working?

Comment: It is more interesting to study why `count += 10` doesn't work. In the assignment `count = count + 10`, `count` in the right hand side will be treated just as a value and be implicitly unwrapped (as is specified for implicitly unwrapped optionals). The `count += 10` case, however, is just sugar for the call to the `+=` function providing a reference to _the value_ of `count` and a copy of the right hand side: `(+=)(&count, 10)`. But since `count` is an implicitly unwrapped optional, its (implicit) value is immutable, and this is equal to the call `(+=)(&(immutable_value_representation), 10)`.

Comment: ... and you may naturally not pass an immutable property as an `inout` parameter (which is precisely what the `lhs` of the `+=` operator is). The key here is the immutability of the implicitly unwrapped value, which is also mentioned in the duplicate target.

Comment: (... if `count` is explicitly unwrapped, as e.g. in my first comment above, the wrapped value (if it exists) can naturally be mutated if the property is a mutable one: it's only when the wrapped value is provided implicitly that the value representation will be immutable).

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work because the compound assignment operator `+=` expects the left side to be a mutable `Int` variable. When you pass it `count`, the compiler unwraps the implicitly unwrapped optional and sends an immutable `Int` value instead, which cannot be passed as the `inout` parameter that `+=` expects.

If you really want to do this, you can overload `+=`:

```
func += (left: inout Int!, right: Int) {
    left = left! + right
}
```

Now `+=` sends the left side as an implicitly unwrapped optional without unwrapping it, and the unwrapping is done explicitly inside the function.

```
var count: Int! = 10
count = count + 10 // 20
count += 10 // 30
```

Comment: so why count + 10 is working ?

Comment: This answer is not correct. In the expression `count += 10`, `count` will implicitly be unwrapped into a concrete (`Int`) value, but that value _will be immutable_ (a property of the wrapped value representation of an implicitly unwrapped optional _when it is provided implicitly_). Since the first argument (or left hand side) of the `+=` method(/operator) is an `inout` parameter, naturally you may not pass immutable properties to it.

Comment: (... The custom `+=` operator above just provides a more specific overload for the case when `lhs` is of type (`inout`) `Int!` and `rhs` is of type `Int`. This means there will be no need to implicitly unwrap `count` in the call `count += 10` (to match the overload `(+=)(inout Int, Int)`), since there is a perfect overload match for that call. The body of the overload, however, explicitly unwraps the wrapped value, allowing mutation of it).

Comment: @dfri I didn't realize it was actually unwrapping the optional; from the error message I assumed it didn't even try. I edited my answer.